# Fuse.js with nested data returns wrong ID

Tags: javascript, fuse.js

Im using http://fusejs.io/ to search some json data.
The data is big list of cabinets that each contain n number of items.

Data example:

```
{"cabinets":[
  {"cabinet":"A4","items":[ 
    {"title":"Toys","keywords":"leksaker, pingpong, kendama, pingis","id":"98"},
    {"title":"Skisch Grand Prix","keywords":"Pokal, cup, pris, skisch","id":"99"},{"title":"Lamp prototype","keywords":"lamp-prototyp","id":"100"}]},
  {"cabinet":"B4","items":[
    {"title":"Screens (LCD)","keywords":"skärm display","id":"30"},
    {"title":"Displays","keywords":"screen skärm","id":"31"},
    {"title":"Lampor","keywords":"","id":"32"}]}
...
```

The search looks at the title and the keywords of an items, I want it to return the id of the matched item.

```
.then(function (response) {
  $scope.cabinets = response.data.cabinets;
  var options = {
    shouldSort: false,
    threshold: 0.3,
    location: 0,
    distance: 100,
    maxPatternLength: 32,
    minMatchCharLength: 2,
    keys: ["items.title","items.keywords"],
    id: "items.id"
  };

  fuse = new Fuse($scope.cabinets, options);
});
```

Problem is that when I search for "Displays", it returns the ID for "Screens (LCD" which is the first item of the cabinet. Same thing happens if I search for "Lampor".

This is not the specified behavior according to: http://fusejs.io/#searching-by-id

Can anyone spot my error?

Comment: I'm also having the same problem. Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Im afraid I didnt